# What's with the bump in traffic at 8pm EST on Friday?

Tags: discussion, traffic

I noticed that during this hour the questions asked got a lot more views than any of the questions asked before or after.  This one in particular had over 500 views in a short period of time:

- [How to disable all "home" keys](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1843/how-to-disable-all-home-keys)

Then these all had over a hundred:

- [How can I view my Google Analytics data on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1844/anyone-knows-an-application-on-android-to-view-my-google-analytics-data)
- [Can you see your groups and pages in the Facebook for Android application?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1846/can-you-see-your-gruops-and-pages-in-the-facebook-for-android-application)
- [Can I install live wallpaper on a Samsung Galaxy 3?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1851/live-wallpaper-for-samsung-galaxy-3)

Where as the questions that followed are currently at 18 and 55 views and the five questions that precede them haven't broken 25 views.

Are those questions just that more interestesing?

Comment: Maybe a cross post from somewhere?  No way to tell without access to google analytic data (or whatever SE collects)

Comment: Yeah, I did a backlinks search but got nothing.